# How to set spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount with RabbitMQ consumers on autoscale environment?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I'm running RabbitMq consumers using the spring cloud infrastructure. The documentation state the following:

> `spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount`
> The number of deployed instances of an application. Must be set for partitioning on the producer side. **Must be set on the consumer side when using RabbitMQ** and with Kafka if autoRebalanceEnabled=false.
> Default: `1`.
> `spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex`
> The instance index of the application: A number from 0 to instanceCount - 1. Used for partitioning with RabbitMQ and with Kafka if autoRebalanceEnabled=false. Automatically set in Cloud Foundry to match the application’s instance index.

My consumers are running on an auto-scaling environment - when the queue is getting above a threshold, more consumer instances are raised, and when it gets down again some consumers are shutdown.

So how should I define those parameters?
Are they really mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties are only applicable when using partitioned queues.

The rabbitmq binder does not support auto-scaling when using partitioning.

As long as you are not using partitioning, you can ignore them.

Comment: If that's the case then the documentation is very misleading in `Must be set on the consumer side when using RabbitMQ` without stating partitioning.

Comment: I suggest you open a documentation issue against the project on GitHub.